Turn off neovim messages in VSCode
I am getting annoying output from VSCode Neovim. For example anytime I search in a file for a string and the pattern is not found, the Output opens with messages from Neovim:

I guess it might have something to do with me debugging Nvim problems a while back and perhaps turning these messages on, but I don't remember where and how. I already:

checked my VSCode settings and nvim init file and can't find any relevant settings there
set "vscode-neovim.neovimClean": true to disable Nvim plugins, even though I can't see the plugins could be to blame

Any idea how to turn these Nvim messages off? I also don't want to completely get rid of the vscode-neovim messages channel since I still need to know about errors if they happen, like when there is an init error.

Edit: Sep 15 2024
This issue resurfaced even with Nvim 0.10 and all deps up to date while using VimSneak (search was working fine at this point).
So I went down to the vscode-neovim code and found that when a command output line count is higher than cmdheight, it pops up the Nvim output. That's exactly the case with VimSneak when I am searching for eg. h3 string. It produces an output like this ['>', '>h', '>h3', 'not found: h3'] of length 4 which is higher than the cmdheight=3 suggested in the related GH issue, and the Output gets shown.

So to get rid of this annoyance I am using (Lua)
vim.o.cmdheight=4

which I am sure might have some unwanted side-effects but for me it's still better than having Output shown to me all the time.

Original answer:
It seems people get this problem with Nvim 0.9 https://github.com/vscode-neovim/vscode-neovim/issues/2046. In my case, I had a Ubuntu PPA 0.10.0-dev distro, but had the same problem. When I upgraded to using stable 0.10, this issue got resolved.

What is the version of Neovim?
The cmdheight=0 option added since v0.10 may help you.
There is also a related issue: https://github.com/vscode-neovim/vscode-neovim/issues/2109

It's 0.10, and I already have cmdheight=0. The Output is still popping up.

set the cmdheight = 1 in the init.lua file.
Ref: https://github.com/vscode-neovim/vscode-neovim/issues/2109#issuecomment-2171410407
I had the same annoying effect. This resolved in my case. Add the below at the beginning of the init.lua file.
if vim.g.vscode then
  cmdheight = 1 -- this is the new line I added
  return
end

-- rest of the nvim config


This still causes the messages to appear when using VimSneak.
